# Any shortcut for updating join table when creating one of the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, let us say we have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :networks, through: user_networks
    has_many :user_networks
end

class Network< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: user_networks
    has_many :user_networks
end

class UserNetwork < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :network
end
```

Is there a shortcut for doing the following in a controller:

```
@network = Network.create(params[:network])
UserNetwork.create(user_id: current_user.id, network_id: @network.id)
```

Just curious and I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
current_user.networks.create(params[:network])
```

But your code implies you are not using [`strong_parameters`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html), or checking the validation of your objects. Your controller should contain:

```
def create
  @network = current_user.networks.build(network_params)

  if @network.save
    # good response
  else
    # bad response
  end
end

private

def network_params
  params.require(:network).permit(:list, :of, :safe, :attributes)
end
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm still used to Rails 3. I'm using strong parameters.

Comment: Though it seems this should, it didn't work. Then again. Is build supposed to associate with the user automatically?

Comment: @David do you have more details about how it didn't work? Log, etc? Have you tried in the console? That will be quicker to debug.